# open sub menu onclick and close opened sub menu

Tags: jquery, css, menu, slidetoggle, slideup

I'm using a JS code to dispay sub menu from menu by clicking on li items.
when I click on a li item, when sub menu slideToggle and if a sub menu is already openned then it's slideUp. It works perfectly.

But I have juste one issue, when clicking on a li from my sub menu, it slideUp and then SlideToggle again, how can I prevent this ?

Here is my jquery :

```
$("#menu li").click(function () {
    $('ul.sub-menu').not( $(this).children() ).slideUp();
    $(this).children("ul.sub-menu").slideToggle();
});
```

and here is what I've tried so far without success :

```
$("#menu li").not($('#menu li sub-menu li a')).click(function () {
    $('ul.sub-menu').not( $(this).children() ).slideUp();
    $(this).children("ul.sub-menu").slideToggle();
});
```

here is my html :

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">1</a></li>
<li>2
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="#">2.1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2.2</a></li>
</ul> 
</li>
<li>3
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="#">3.1</a></li>
</ul> 
</li>
<li><a href="#">4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">6</a></li>
</ul>
```

and my CSS :

```
.sub-menu {display:none}
```

and a Jsfiddle to see it in action :

http://jsfiddle.net/2s023cfc/1/

can anybody help me with this ?
thanks

Comment: replace the first `.not()` selector for a direct child selector. `>`

Answer (score 2):

Specify the most to which element you are targeting the event in JQuery!

```js
$("#menu > li > a").click(function () {
    $('ul.sub-menu').not($(this).siblings()).slideUp();
    $(this).siblings("ul.sub-menu").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
    display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">3.1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">6</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't have any href on my 2 and 3 li. is it possible to do it without having to add an href ?

Comment: Well, the thing is you have to attach JQuery events to a specific element. Without wrapping the 2/3 into something makes it difficult to target. I mean, with your current code, you are targeting the 2/3 AND the ul inside the clicked li.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This-**

```
  $("#menu li").not($('#menu li sub-menu li a')).click(function (e) {
        $('ul.sub-menu').not( $(this).children() ).slideUp();
        $(this).children("ul.sub-menu").slideToggle();
        e.stopPropagation()
    });
```

You need to stop propagation.