# Dropdown menu on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried numerous JS queries and none seem to be working.

I want to only show my dropdown menus when the list item they relate to is clicked, they need to show until the user either clicks off the ul or clicks a link.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="sub-nav">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <a href="#"><li class="active">All</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Videos</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Images</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Maps</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>News</li></a>
      <a href="#">
        <li id="has-sub">More
          <ul>
            <a href="#"><li>Shopping</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Books</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Flights</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Apps</li></a>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li id="search-tools">Search Tools
          <ul>
            <a href="#"><li id="has-sub">Any Country</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li id="has-sub">Any Time</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li id="has-sub">All Results</li></a>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your html is wrong. Element `a` not allowed as child of element `ul`.

Comment: anchor tags should be inside the li

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003519/open-sub-menu-onclick-and-close-opened-sub-menu

Comment: _"I have tried numerous JS queries and none seem to be working"_ - Is your Plugin correctly implemented? jQuery correctly loaded? Correct jQuery Version? Correct markup? Have you included the Styles that usually get shipped with a Plugin?

Comment: yeah it should be <li><a href="#">Shopping</a></li>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("li:has(ul)").click(function(){
$("ul",this).toggle('slow');
});
```

Make sure you have the jQuery library.

Comment: really appreciate it.. But I got a downvote too.. my question was to that person

Answer (score 0):

Load jQuery library alternatively you can use like this.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Apply style to your menu html as below

```
<style>
    li > ul{display:none;}
    .show {display:block;}
</style>
```

Now this is what you are looking for.

```
<script>
    jQuery("li:has(ul)").click(function(){
        jQuery("ul",this).toggleClass('show');
    });
</script>
```

```js
$("li:has(ul)").click(function(){
  $("ul",this).toggleClass('show');
});
```

```css
li > ul{display:none;}
.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sub-nav">
                <div class="container">

                    <ul>
                        <a href="#"><li class="active">All</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li>Videos</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li>Images</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li>Maps</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li>News</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li id="has-sub">More
                            <ul>
                                <a href="#"><li>Shopping</li></a>
                                <a href="#"><li>Books</li></a>
                                <a href="#"><li>Flights</li></a>
                                <a href="#"><li>Apps</li></a>
                            </ul>
                        </li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li id="search-tools">Search Tools
                            <ul>
                                <a href="#"><li id="has-sub">Any Country</li></a>
                                <a href="#"><li id="has-sub">Any Time</li></a>
                                <a href="#"><li id="has-sub">All Results</li></a>
                            </ul>
                        </li></a>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Use `jQuery` instead of $, because some frameworks or cms tools have conflict with it. So `jQuery` works always.

Answer (score 0):

In this solution dropdown menus collapse when a link is clicked as you asked.

```js
$('a').click(function(){
    $('.container ul:not(:first-child)').hide();
  if($(this).next().is('ul')){
    $(this).next().toggle('slow');
  }
});
```

```css
ul ul{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sub-nav">
                <div class="container">

                    <ul>
                        <a href="#"><li class="active">All</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li>Videos</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li>Images</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li>Maps</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li>News</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li id="has-sub">More
                            <ul>
                                <a href="#"><li>Shopping</li></a>
                                <a href="#"><li>Books</li></a>
                                <a href="#"><li>Flights</li></a>
                                <a href="#"><li>Apps</li></a>
                            </ul>
                        </li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li id="search-tools">Search Tools
                            <ul>
                                <a href="#"><li id="has-sub">Any Country</li></a>
                                <a href="#"><li id="has-sub">Any Time</li></a>
                                <a href="#"><li id="has-sub">All Results</li></a>
                            </ul>
                        </li></a>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="sub-nav">
            <div class="container">

                <ul>
                     <li class="active">All</li>  
                     <li>Videos</li>  
                     <li>Images</li>  
                     <li>Maps</li>  
                     <li>News</li>  
                     <li id="has-sub">More
                        <ul>
                            <li>Shopping</li>  
                            <li>Books</li>  
                            <li>Flights</li>  
                            <li>Apps</li>  
                        </ul>
                    </li>  
                     <li id="search-tools">Search Tools
                        <ul>
                             <li id="has-sub">Any Country</li>  
                             <li id="has-sub">Any Time</li>  
                             <li id="has-sub">All Results</li>  
                        </ul>
                    </li>  
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
```

this should work